# Acoustic perfume

Tags: meaning

What is the exact meaning of "acoustic perfume" in the sentence:

Let's get out of here - this acoustic perfume is too much for my ears.

Comment: It's a synesthetic metaphor (smell-hearing) meaning that the ambient music/audio annoys the speaker.

Comment: It means noise that is floating around the room like perfume.

Comment: So it has a negative connotation. It looks strange to use"perfume" for something unpleasant.

Comment: @Josh61 At American malls, there is the classic [perfume gauntlet](http://www.coloribus.com/adsarchive/tv-commercials/footwearclothes-retailer-perfume-gauntlet-2126755/).

Comment: @Josh61 The implication is that it is overpowering perfume, because it's driving the person away. *Perfume* is neutral. *Fragrance* would generally be positive, unless it is being used sarcastically.

Comment: @ Spehro Pefhany 
Perfume  n.
1. A substance that emits and diffuses a fragrant odor, especially a volatile liquid distilled from flowers or prepared synthetically.
2. A pleasing, agreeable scent or odor. See Synonyms at fragrance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Perfume" can become negative if one applies too much perfume such that it becomes *overpowering*. Your example is specifically comparing the noise in the environment to over-applied, overpowering perfume.

Or, in other words, the noise is too loud, too distracting or simply not tasteful. The speaker is most likely referring to any music being played.